# About redefining a name of Java method with a typo for simplicity sake

Tags: java

I type fast and usually make a lot of typos that I have to fix constantly while printing. For instance, if I work with method *getCompany()*, I often write it as *getComapny()* that irritates me greatly. Is it considered to be a good practice to wrap *getCompany()* method into *getComapny()* not to bother about this typo anymore? Like having

```
public Company getCompany(){
  Company company = new Company();
  //do some really important stuff in here
  return company;
}
```

and to wrap it with

```
public Company getComapny(){
  return getCompany();
}
```

I think my fellow colleagues who will support the code after me wil be thankful, they have the same problems as far as I aware.

BTW, how to conceal *getComapny()* from JavaDoc to display *getCompany()* only?

Comment: I can't really see this ending any way other than poorly...

Comment: Wow the first two times I read this I thought you meant you originally *defined* the method as `getComapny` and that was released as an API that you had to support after.  You're seriously thinking about *adding the misspelled version **intentionally**,* just to save yourself the odd annoyance because you type too fast?  Use an IDE dude.

Comment: Do some training to improve your accuracy.

Comment: I'm guessing the fun tag indicates this is not serious.  I hope.

Comment: -1 Are you really serious about this question?!?

Comment: Guys, why being so serious Thursday afternoon?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'm really hoping that this post is a joke.  I pity the poor person who would have to maintain that code in the future.  How many misspellings do you want to support?

```
public Company getComapny(){
public Company getCmopany(){
public Company getCompayn(){
public Company getCoampny(){
public Company getCimpany(){
public Company getCimapny(){
public Company getCimapyn(){
```

Especially when any decent IDE has things like `CTRL-SPACE` autocomplete for method names.  Which would be **faster** than actually typing the method name yourself.  **Please tell me this is a joke.**  I think my brain is melting.

Answer (score 15):

Would it be good to add misspellings to your dictionary in MSOffice so you don't see so many red lines.

Other people should be able to read what you said anyway.

Bad bad idea.

Comment: Agree with @Xaade, this is an *awful* idea.  Simply suck it up and **refactor**.

Comment: It's worse than you think @Kirk.  It doesn't even need refactoring.

Answer (score 4):

Typing fast with a lot of typos isn't typing fast at all, it is typing slowly. Very slowly, taking into account the correction cycle.

Slow down and speed yourself up.

And don't build your own personal bugs into the application. Take them *out.*

Answer (score 1):

> Is it considered to be a good practice
>   to wrap getCompany() method into
>   getComapny() not to bother about this
>   typo anymore?

I don't think you could do worse than this. Take a look at [Logback news](http://logback.qos.ch/news.html). New version breaks compatibility with previous verions because of one measly misspelled letter (version pre 0.9.28 had "bithTime" instead of "birthTime"). You should do the same yourself. Rename every instance of your misspelled method to a proper one and force your users to use the new version.

Wrapping an existing problem will only make it worse in the long run, maintenance wise.

By the way: invest more time in proper typing. You can be the fastest typer in the world, but if you're making mistakes in every sentence, your speed won't do you much good.

Answer (score 1):

You suggest taking a mistake (the typo) and rather than eliminate it, allow it to propagate instead. Code that is not rejected by the compiler tends to be copy/pasted, used as an example and so on. After a while, the typos will be all over the place, regardless if they exist in the "official" documentation.

Not to mention any newcomers that will be confused about the "proper" names that should be used. There are quite a few people out there that have had to settle with mispelled identifiers that has sneaked in legacy code - these people would not see anything extremely strange in using a mispelled name routinely.

In short: unless you already have tons of legacy code that cannot be reasonably converted, you should not allow typos to propagate, let alone introduce them as a matter of course.

Answer (score 0):

Dont do the type-o. That is just annoying.
Maybe you should call the method createCompany(), or buildCompany(), or some other builder/factory (depending on what is done in the commented out section) standard.

As for concealing it, the only way I know of is to make the method private.

Answer (score 0):

Wrap the code like you explained above, mark the `getComapny` method as deprecated, and remove it as soon as possible.

Unless your code is externally published and needs to retain compatibility, go through a signature correction on all your code, wich is plainless with pretty much any IDE. Guess you'll be happier then.

But still, a typo may look bad, but it will only bother the coders if the code itself is nice. If you are talking about spaghetti code, nobody will care about a typo.